# EWS updating message body not triggering outlook redownload of the message

Tags: python, outlook, vsto, exchangewebservices

I am using Exchange Web Services (EWS) with python,
I used "UpdateItem" (soap request) to update message (IPF.Note) body and subject,
i can see the changes in OWA but outlook not fetching the updated message under any circumstances,
is there any property or another method i need to use to make outlook notice the change and download the message again?

I tried to use the Update Folder button and still nothing.
I am using outlook 2016 with Exchange online (Office 365).

Answer (score 0):

OK,
I have found kind of solution,
outlook only pulling the message again if the message moved to different folder,
so i moved the message to another folder (junk) and back to the original folder
and then outlook fetched the updated message.

I know it's not the best solution though